# Negative css line not scaling correctly with a 100% svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

Hope I can explain this correctly.

Please see the attached fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldd70cnd/

Basically, I have an svg image that will be 100% width, I then want to add 2 coloured lines, 1 above and 1 below but I want the lines to be within the svg's boundary, see images.

[image: Fist image]
The above example shows the lines on the very edge of the svg image.

[image: Second image]

The above example shows you where I want the lines, my jsfiddle has got the top line working fine, the bottom line doesn't stay in line if you resize the browser.

Can anyone help?

Here's the css i've used.

```
.logo-top-line { 
    height:2px; 
    width:100%; 
    background : rgb(88, 168, 144);
    margin-top:3%;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:-2.6%;
}
.logo-bottom-line { 
    height:2px; 
    width:100%; 
    background : rgb(88, 168, 144);
    margin-top:-1em;
}
```

Comment: If it's SVG, why not just add the line into the SVG?

Comment: Sounds like a case for borders to me...or positioning.

Comment: @james Montagne I wanted to use the image again without the lines

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you explain how I can use borders with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldd70cnd/1/

This uses a container with `position: relative` and all of the children get `position: absolute`. The top and bottom lines are then defined based on the relative position of the container's edges.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo-top-line"></div>
    <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/skt2j3581/logo2.png" alt=""/>
    <div class="logo-bottom-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="contact text">Mobile: 000000000000</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.logo-top-line { 
    height:2px; 
    width:100%; 
    background : rgb(88, 168, 144);
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.5%;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.logo-bottom-line { 
    height:2px; 
    width:100%; 
    background : rgb(88, 168, 144);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 11.5%;
}
.contact {
    font-family : Helvetica;
    font-size : 15px;
    line-height : 26.04px;
    color : rgb(31, 80, 108);
}
```